# Wiris editor only works from https and not from file path

Tags: editor

I'm working on a Native iPad App, one of the module is using the wiris editor embedded, when accessing the wiris editor, it says

> Wiris editor only works from https and not from file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/deviceid/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/appid/appname.app/www.index.html

Wiris Editor Instance Code -

```
this.wirisAnswerMathEditor = com.wiris.jsEditor.JsEditor.newInstance({ 'language': 'en' });
```

Comment: You should probably amend the tags because from your description it does not seem to have anything to do with TinyMCE or CKEditor. Wiris Editor is a different product and your tags will make it difficult to find relevant answers.

Comment: We have an offline WIRIS version for cases like yours. Please contact us at info@wiris.com for further details.